# Promise Recursion | async canvas painting

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, recursion, canvas, promise

I have a canvas and I have a tensorflowjs model. The canvas is being painted with the maximum fps of the camera. But my TensorflowJS Model only can achieve 5 FPS due to calculation time. What I want to achieve is that the canvas paints with steady 60 FPS from the camera and that it uses the temporary result of the AI. So the AI has to run somewhere seperately and save the value into a global variable. I have something like this:

```
    let currFace;
    let net;
    let currVideo;

    facemesh.load().then(model => {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("model.loaded"))
        net = model;
    });

    async function inference() {
        currFace = await net.estimateFaces(currVideo)
        inference();
    }

    document.addEventListener("canvas.repaint", async e => {
            const {ctx, video} = e.detail.payload;
            ctx.fillStyle = "#c82124";
            currVideo = video;
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

            if (currFace && currFace.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < currFace.length; i++) {
                    if (currFace[i].faceInViewConfidence > 0.5) {
                        const [bx, by] = currFace[i].boundingBox.topLeft;
                        const w = currFace[i].boundingBox.bottomRight[0] - bx;
                        const h = currFace[i].boundingBox.bottomRight[1] - by;
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
                        ctx.stroke();

                        const keypoints = currFace[i].scaledMesh;
                        // Log facial keypoints.
                        for (let i = 0; i < keypoints.length; i++) {
                            const [x, y, z] = keypoints[i];
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                            ctx.stroke();
                            ctx.fill();
                        }
                    } else {
                        ctx.fillText("No face on screen", 10, 50);
                    }
                }
            } else if (net) {
                currFace = await net.estimateFaces(currVideo);
                inference();
            }
        }
    );
```

The important part is the inference() call and the function itself. I get 100% cpu usage and the website isnt usable (main thread blocked...) any ideas?

Comment: What is `net.estimateFaces`, does it actually do something asynchronous and return a promise?

Comment: Verified, it does return a Promise @Bergi

Comment: And what does it do? Does it run heavy computations on the main thread? How did you achieve the 5 FPS, did you have 100% cpu usage there as well?

Comment: What is triggering the `canvas.repaint` event? This `if`/`else` looks like it could start the `inference()` loop multiple times.

Comment: It does do heavy calculations, I'm not a js expert but I do think it runs on the main thread? the `canvas.repaint` event is being triggered every time by a recursive function using the requestAnimationFrame method.  @Bergi

Comment: I also verified => the recursion is only started once @Bergi

Comment: Hard to see that the recursion is guaranteed to be started only once. The initial `currFace = await net.estimateFaces(video)` assignment won't happen until the `net.estimateFaces(video)` promise has fulfilled. In the meantime, 'canvas.repaint' may have been re-triggered, in which case further interleaved `inference()` recursion(s) will be set in motion. Setting `currFace` *synchronously* to `[]` before starting the recursion should fix it. ie `if (currFace && currFace.length > 0) { ... } else { currFace = []; inference(); }`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 whoah, didn't even think about that. Nice catch! Will try it out!

Comment: Will try it tomorrow. I have to add tho that I think that if you dispatchEvent() an Event, it is synchronous and waits for all listeners to finish. Idk if its the case for this here, but I also got only one console.log inside that if every time. But still will look into it

Comment: As javascript is single threaded, event threads do indeed get queued. However, whilst `inference()` recursion(s) are brought to life by 'canvas.repaint' thread(s), each one will become a series of threads - due to the `await net.estimateFaces(currVideo)`. This gives opportunity for further 'canvas.repaint' threads to be triggered and handled.

Comment: Despite contrary comments JavaScript is multi threaded via the webWorkers API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API Tensorflow has web worker support https://medium.com/@wl1508/webworker-in-tensorflowjs-49a306ed60aa . You can have your main thread present the video and tensorflow do its thing without blocking the main thread. A simple message listener can keep the current tensorflow  results up to date. It is also possible  to have zero copy data transfer between workers (video pixels) Note theads only provide befit on multi (or hyper) core devices

Comment: Not exactly. Web workers provide multi-threading but without making Javascript itself multi-threaded.

Comment: I don't think that Tensorflow having web worker support is relevant here, other than making my case for the recommended fix stronger, but I'll think about it overnight.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 JS execution context is Blocking, I.E. it can not be interrupted (well apart from the execution timeout on some browsers) Technically Multi threading is a CPU/OS feature.

Comment: https://medium.com/jspoint/achieving-parallelism-in-javascript-using-web-workers-8f921f2d26db

Comment: @Roamer-1888 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing) JS is also  parallel with shared mem support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer and from MDN *"When memory is shared, multiple threads* (JavaScript) *can read and write the same data in memory."*  second paragraph https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics#Description

Comment: @Roamer-1888 but this if will be executed multiple times which you provided since the currFace.length is still below 1

Comment: Also, as I mentioned the recursion only gets started once (set a console.log). I do have to add that this is only happening when there is a Notice: "WebGL is not supported on this device". But that seems quite obvious.

Comment: What is your test to show it starts only once?

Comment: Simplify the test to if (currFace) {. The test for `currFace.length > 0` can disappear.

Comment: I console.log everytime it reaches that second if

Comment: Issue still exists, maybe I should just drop it since almost every device supports WebGL